# Why is it important to align bones to view axis?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I'm watching a tutorial on Youtube about leg IK rigging and this menu gets pulled up to align bones to view axis[image].

1. What is this menu called and how can I access it without hot keys?
2. Why is this important?  Are there additional resources I can read to better understand? It was difficult to google.

Answer (score 1):

The operation is "recalculate roll."  It can be accessed from the armature menu, via armature-> bone roll-> recalculate roll-> whatever.

You don't necessarily have to align bones to the view axis specifically.  What you want to do, though, is make sure your bones have appropriate tilts.  Using the recalculate roll option to do so is the easiest way to control your tilt.  (I tend to recalculate to cursor myself.)

Why?  Think about a lower arm bone.  Your elbow rotates in a single axis, more or less, and if you animate a model where its lower arm rotates outside of this axis, it's going to look broken.  So you're either going to use angle limits, or transform locks, or IK angle limits, or expect the animator to animate in specific bone-local axes.  Doing any of these requires that you set the tilt such that the unlocked axis corresponds to the way you actually want the elbow to bend.

In the case of Euler transforms, this is even more important.  An XYZ Euler interpolates well with X rotation, but once you start combining it with Y and Z rotation, you can get some funky, counterintuitive interpolation.  So an Euler bone should be set such that its X axis rotation corresponds with the most likely, most extreme rotation with which it's going to be animated.

Answer (score 0):

In *Edit* mode, select the bone and in the header menu > *Armature > Bone Roll > Recalculate Roll*. If you don't have any reason to align the bones with the axis, don't.

[image]

Comment: Thanks – can you help explain why I *would* want to do this? The tutorial mentioned its really important.

Comment: I guess for example if a bone has a Copy Rotation constraint with a particular axis, it's better that both this bone and the bone it copies are correctly oriented, same thing if you want to limit the rotation of a bone etc?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the tutorial in question took pains to create some major rotational axes that just happened to be oriented to the global, world axes.  My evidence is that the character looks simplified and probably has a perfectly vertical joint chain for a spine.  The arms are orthogonal to the view, too.  In that context, aligning to view ("world") would be the standard and why they said it was "important".  Now imagine a natural humanoid in an A-pose.  The hand is tilted at an angle and so are it's fingers.  How now, brown cow?

Re-calculate roll to the rescue.

I've used this feature to align to "active bone" on occasion.
My use-case was this:  I had fingers on which I had adjusted the joint *positions*.
(I translated them in space to be at specific *locations*)
This led to their *orientations* becoming out of plane with one another.
That is, a finger's rotational axes were no longer *parallel* to each other.

Here's an image of a posed index finger with it's bones in plane with each other: Note that they pivot on X and that those X axes are all parallel.
[image: finger joints' rotational axes should be parallel]

I needed to re-align the joint rolls without changing their positions.
Entering Edit mode, I adjusted the knuckle-joint's 'Roll' until it's Z-axis was pointing, visually, "up" from the knuckle.  "Recalculate Roll" is the tool I needed to make sure that the two child joints have their Y-Z planes along the same plane as the knuckle joint.  Like in my example image, the bone direction is along positive-Y and I want them all to rotate in the same plane when pivoting on X.
Still in edit mode, I selected all three joints, making sure to select the knuckle *last*,making it the "Active" selection.
I invoked the Recalculate Roll (SHFT-N) and choose "Active Bone".
The second and third joints adjust their roll to be in plane with the Active Bone.

Mind, you can always eyeball this kind of alignment, but the Recalculate Roll function does it fast, easy, and mathematically precise.
Hope this is accurate and helps!